# Risk of leaving isolated Windows Server 2003 unpatched vs. risk of connecting to Internet

Tags: security, windows-update, virus

I've got a legacy Windows Server 2003 R2 machine that runs a security camera network.  It seems to be mostly isolated from the Internet now, but there are various legacy remote access mechanisms built into the video server.  The machine is on the local LAN, at a school with lots of dodgy student laptops.

The server has security patches turned to "manual install" probably 5-10 years ago.  I applied all the patches that had collected just today.

How would you handle the next step... just opening the machine to the Internet has a risk, even just to collect whatever patches are out there.  Leaving it as is could result in a from-LAN compromise.

Comment: I would take it offline, personally, or upgrade it to a support version of Windows Server

Comment: I couldn't agree more... try migrating it over to a newer version of Windows Server and doing a cutover at some point in an in-place upgrade is not an option. If the vendor doesn't support newer Windows OSes ask what you need to do to have it supported such as a newer software version, etc. Otherwise, do NOT expose this machine to the Internet as that's not in your best interest for security. I would try putting it behind a FW or router ACL rules with explicit IP address access policies only for single machines only to connect to it as well as lock down Windows FW with relevant rules as well.

Comment: So a FW or router and OS FW rules would tighten down the LAN side, not connecting to the Internet WAN would take care of exposing it at this level, but I'd still update the latest WU security patches even if that means you do it manually. Otherwise, it's time to update this thing, reach out to the vendor for support, upgrade the software to be support, migrate and/or cut it over, etc. If you're the IT guy, then advise the school what the right thing to do is and if they don't go for that, then start locking it down with EXPLICIT IP address rules and block EVERYTHING else and apply WU patches.

Comment: This might be a good candidate for a virtual server too I suppose if that's applicable or an option for you... Just thinking quick ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already running an unsupported operating system the best thing you should do is upgrade to a newer os. if you can't so that configure your local and network firewall to only allow connections to the cameras themselves and whatever management/viewing consoles your require. As long as the system is isolated, running an outdated os is not that big of a deal.